# Display Out of Stock at the end of the product list and search result page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have already tried the method mentioned here on SO and other forums but it is not working. I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 and I would like to move all the Out of Stock products to the end of the product list and search result page.

Here is what I tried:

I made a copy of Collection.php from `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/` to  `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/` and pasted below code at the begining of addAttributeToSort function.

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('_inventory_table' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')), '_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status'));
$this->getSelect()->order('stock_status DESC');
```

it didn't work though and I prefer an option that can be done via the magento theme instead of editing core files and copying it over to local directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be looking to implement a more direct approach in the list.phtml file or with a function in the corresponding class file eg Yourpackage/Yourmodule/Block/Product/List.php.

You can access stock levels of each `$_product` using this code

```
  $cabac_stockObject = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product); 
  //get the stock levels
  $cabac_stockQuantityAvailable = (int)$cabac_stockObject->getQty() - (int)$cabac_stockObject->getMinimumQty(); //returns string! Like 10.000 or 0.0000 for 10 or 0 so cast to (int)  
  $cabac_stockStatus = (int)$cabac_stockObject->getIsInStock(); //returns string! Like 10.000 or 0.0000 for 10 or 0 so cast to (int)
```

And then maybe loop over the collection, add the product object and stock count into an array, sort by stock count and then pass the sorted array into your `list.phtml`'s `foreach` loop.

So something like this (apologies for rough pseudo code)

```
   foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
      $cabac_stockObject = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product); 
      //get the stock levels
      $cabac_stockQuantityAvailable = (int)$cabac_stockObject->getQty() - (int)$cabac_stockObject->getMinimumQty();
      $cabac_stockStatus = (int)$cabac_stockObject->getIsInStock(); 

    if($cabac_stockQuantityAvailable==0 || $cabac_stockStatus==0 ){
      $cabac_stockQuantityAvailable = 0;
    }
    //store the stock quantity and $_product in an array

  }

//sort the array as you see fit
//foreach ($sortedArray['products'] as $_product){

  //display the products

//}
```